# "Drupal already installed" Message on Restored site

Tags: database, installation

We had an issue on a Drupal 8.8.2 site, had to restore DB, Core and Vendor, now anyone visiting the site gets the site as normal, but if admin logs in I receive:

Drupal 8.8.2
Drupal already installed
- To start over, you must empty your existing database and copy default.settings.php over settings.php.
- To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the update script.
- View your existing site.

Of note:
Rather then restore over existing db I created a db2, restored the DB to it and pointed the settings to it (not sure if that is the issue)

I can't figure out how to stop that page from loading. I don't want to start over, running the update script does nothing but bring me back to the same page. View your existing site does take me to site but can't edit anything (looks like it just logs me out).

Comment: I had to restore a site recently and a similar issue, not sure if exactly the same.  Fix for me was that I needed to also delete the config folder with the long hash name inside `sites`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion....Just tried that, now it goes to the Install Wizard.

Comment: Going through Wizard gets me right back to same place.

Comment: Check your MySQL logs for error messages (e.g. closed connections). You may have run into a problem with too low packet sizes in your MySQL server configuration. `max_allowed_packet` is your friend then.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing the install page on an already installed Drupal site usually is a sign of problems with your database connection before the request has been processed by PHP.

This may have a wide range of causes, most likely related to your database server configuration.

The first thing to check is your database logs, which may give a hint on how to solve your issue.

We often experienced a similar behavior on sites that heavily use the database. E.g. sending big queries when rebuilding page caches on complex pages. The solution there was to ensure a high enough `max_allowed_packet` setting. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/packet-too-large.html) for more details on how to do that.

Comment: True, I increased the max allowed packet and it works fine, thank you very much

Answer (score -4):

Open you XAMPP server follow the following steps
MySQL>Config>my.ini
It will opena notepad file serach for *max_allowed_packet* and then increase the size as per your needs